# How do you see the pre-DOM markup of HTML5 tags in Chrome and Firefox dev tools

Tags: html, developer-tools

I was reading an article about the HTML5 progress element at [css-tricks.com](http://css-tricks.com/html5-progress-element/) and about 1/8 down the page I noticed an example of how to style the element using the two pseudo-classes `-webkit-progress-bar` and `-webkit-progress-value`. From the screenshot you can see that the classes are used with a pseudo-attribute on two div containers but when I use the progress element in my own example I can't see the divs anywhere.

Is there a clever setting in Chrome dev tools that I need to enable or do I need to rely on a javascript DOM-event to view the markup? Is there a similar solution in Firebug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called the shadow DOM. To access it in Chrome/Chromium open the DevTools settings and check "Show user agent shadow DOM"

[image: Chrome DevTools]

and the result is:

[image]

Comment: Better late than never but this was exactly what I was looking for - thanks alpipego :-)